# Read artifact lists from Nexus, but tooManyResults=true

Tags: java, nexus

I am trying to list all artifacts with given groupId from my company Nexus 2.14 through

```
http://inf-rep:8081/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?g=de.something.*
```

This works fine in general, but sometimes the results obviously become too large so that they are truncated, with a tag `<tooManyResults>true</tooManyResults>`. What is the best way to get all the results nevertheless?

Can I receive pages or set a larger upper limit for artifact numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually quite easy: There are parameters `from` and `count` which allow you to page your request. See

https://repository.sonatype.org/nexus-indexer-lucene-plugin/default/docs/path__lucene_search.html